# Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'SharingDelegate' after updating the FBSDKCore to 5.6.0 in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-share, fbsdksharekit

Currently I'm working on an iOS application in swift. In my application I'm using FacebookShare pods(FBSDKCoreKit 4.46.0) for sharing contents to the Facebook. For that I was used FBSDKSharingDelegate. Today I updated the pod to FBSDKCoreKit to 5.6.0. After updating I got some suggestion in my code like

> 'FBSDKSharingDelegate' has been renamed to 'SharingDelegate'

So I changed it to SharingDelegate, also I changed in my code. But now its showing another error,

> Redundant conformance of 'ProductDetailViewController' to protocol
>   'SharingDelegate'

I searched in google, and I didn't get any solution. Please help me.

These are the protocols I'm used in that ViewController class

```
class customViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate, SharingDelegate 
{

}
```

I don't know which protocol is redundant with SharingDelegate.

These are the pod files that I'm using in the project,
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'

```
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController'

pod 'FacebookCore', '0.9.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.9.0'
pod 'FacebookShare', '0.9.0'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.3.0'
pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 3.3.0' 
pod 'GoogleSignIn' 
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' 

pod 'SideMenu'
pod "QRCode"
pod 'SwipeMenuViewController', '~> 2.0.0'
pod "ScrollingFollowView"
pod 'DLRadioButton', '~> 1.4'
pod 'AZDialogView'

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

pod 'SKActivityIndicatorView', '~> 0.1.0'
pod 'SwiftyGif'
pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.6'
pod "ImageSlideshow/Alamofire"
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod "PhotoSlider"
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'CardsLayout'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.2'
pod "SkeletonView"
```

also I'm importing frameworks files in the class,

```
import ImageSlideshow
import AlamofireImage
import CoreLocation
import FacebookShare
import MessageUI
import SKActivityIndicatorView
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import MapKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import FBAudienceNetwork
```

Comment: error says you already conform to that protocol, don't search in google but in your code

Comment: I can't figure it out. Please help me.

Comment: did you do a clean rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did. I quit the Xcode, install the pods one more time and then reopen the Xcode, still showing the same error. It was working before updating the FacebookShare pods. And when I updated the FacebookShare pods, FBSDKCoreKit pod file also updated to 5.6.0. And before updating, I'm using FBSDKSharingDelegate protocol, but after update I got suggestion to change it to SharingDelegate. After that I got this issue.

Comment: Now I commented the SharingDelegate protocol, now I can share the content to Facebook, But I don't get any callbacks in the delegate method. But I need the success callback to make an API call.

Comment: Are you by any chance having an extension of your customViewController in any other places?

Comment: No I checked, I used SharingDelegate protocol in this class only. Also there is no extension for this ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/current/FBSDKShareKit/protocols/fbsdksharingdelegate.html), `SharingDelegate` protocol in it's current version has only three functions:

```
func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didCompleteWithResults results: [String : Any]) {

}

func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didFailWithError error: Error) {

}

func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: Sharing) {

}
```

None of your other protocols override any of those functions, so your issue doesn't happen here.

You probably has an extension that also implements this protocol, I could reproduce the error like this:

```
class FBTestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate, SharingDelegate {

}

extension UIViewController: SharingDelegate {

}
```

Output:

> Redundant conformance of 'FBTestViewController' to protocol 'SharingDelegate'

Search your project for those `SharingDelegate` implementations (probably in extensions) and remove them.

**EDIT**

In your imports, comment this line:

```
//import FBSDKShareKit
```

The `FacebookShare` pod already imports it for you. That is the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi alxlives I searched in my entire project but I didn't implement  SharingDelegate anywhere my project other than this class.

Comment: Can you edit the question with your podfile and the imports you are using in this class? Also, please check if you happens to have a manual Facebook framework linked in the project that may be conflicting with the pod

Comment: Hi I updated my question. Also I checked, I didn't add Facebook framework manually. I added only through pods

Comment: It was working before updating the FacebookShare pods. And when I updated the FacebookShare pods, FBSDKCoreKit pod file also updated to 5.6.0. And before updating, I'm using FBSDKSharingDelegate protocol, but after update I got suggestion to change it to SharingDelegate. After that I got this issue.